# Pass a list to a keycommand or keyenvironment

Tags: lists, loops, key-value

I want to define command or environment using the `keycommand` package and pass a list to one key. In my case this would be a list of images.

To be more explicit: How can I make the following pseudocode work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keycommand}
\newkeyenvironment{images}[im]{
\begin{center}
\for \image in im
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{im}
}
{
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{images}[
im={
image1,
image2,
image3
}
\end{images}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is it an environment? In your example, you don't supply any content for the environment but only a value for the required argument. That is, it looks more as if this should be a command than an environment.

Comment: This is only a minimal example, that's why I don't add any content. The pseude-test-content is `center`...

Comment: That's not the content of the environment. That's part of the definition of the environment. You don't have any content in the environment in the document. Moreover, it isn't clear what kind of content you might want there or how that might affect the way the environment should be defined. Centring can be equally applicable to the macro as the environment. (See my answer below, for example, which centres each image within the grid. The grid itself could also, of course, be centred if required.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's `expl3` using a `\seq` variable and splitting the content of the `\commandkey{im}` macro into sequence items, then looping over those items using a map function, say `\loopfunction`

Basically any loop macro that can split the comma separated value list would do of course.

From the documentation of `keycommand` it's apparent, that this packages uses `etoolbox`, so `\forcsvlist` macros can be used as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_from_clist:Nn {Nx,NV}


\newcommand{\loopovercommandkey}[2][]{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nx \l_tmpa_seq {#2}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
    \loopfunction[#1]{##1}% 
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff



\newcommand{\loopfunction}[2][]{%
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
}

\usepackage{keycommand}
\newkeyenvironment{images}[im]{%
  \begin{center}
    \loopovercommandkey[width=2cm]{\commandkey{im}}
  }
  {%
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{images}[%
im={
ente1,
ente2,
ente3
}]
\end{images}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've never used `keycommand` before and the three duck images are actually the same.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Bonus question: Do you have an idea of how to arrange the images in nxm grid automatically?

Comment: @student: I don't know the term 'bonus question'

Comment: This was just a sloppy way to say that I have an additional question about this topic. After trying your solution I noticed that the images should be arranged in a grid and that this should be done automatically since they are read in by a loop. If you have a more simple idea than cfr, please let me know. But after reading cfr's (well written) answer I thought I should learn latex3 anyway :-).

Comment: Well, 'additional questions' are for new questions, not changing the previous one. `expl3` is nice for many things, actually

Comment: Yes, you are right. Perhaps I should ask it as a new question and delete my edit above. But then cfr's answer should be moved too. Is that possible? If so I would ask it as a new question tomorrow...

Comment: @student: Well, cfr can move the content of the answer to another answer, but not the answer directly (perhaps a moderator can do this, but I doubt this)

Comment: I asked it as a new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312436/pass-a-list-to-a-keycommand-or-keyenvironment-and-arrange-them-in-a-grid. Hope this is better.

Answer (score 2):

The following code defines and illustrates a macro `\images{}`. `\images` takes one mandatory argument which should be a key-value list of options. The minimum sensible list sets the key `images` to a list of one or more image files.

I've defined this as a macro but it could be easily defined using `\NewDocumentEnvironment{images}{m} ...` instead, or used within the definition of an environment.

Key-value syntax for `\images{<key-value options>}`:

- `images={<comma separated list of image files>}`
- `grid=<columns>x<rows>` [default is a 2x2 grid)
- `total width=<dimension>`[default is `\linewidth`]
- `total height=<dimension>` [default is `\textheight`]

The code divides the total width and height by the requested number of rows and columns. It then sets each image provided in the centre of one rectangular cell within the grid, with the first image listed in the top-left and the last in the bottom-right. The top row is filled, then the second, then the third and so on.

The number of images need not match the grid size. TeX will just ignore cells in the grid for which no image is specified. However, you'll get an error if there isn't at least one image in the list and you'll get stuff spilling out of the specified area (and bad box warnings, no doubt) if the number of images exceeds the available cells.

The images are scaled if required to fit within the cells of the grid, keeping the aspect ratio of the originals. However, images are never enlarged - only scaled down to fit if necessary.

For example,

```
\images{%
  images={cath-gadael-chartref,cathod,cath,coeden-nadolig-2014},
}

\images{%
  images={tspcd,cauldron,duck,tiger,example-image-c},
  grid=3x2,
}
```

will produce 2 full-page grids. The first is 2x2 by default and each cell gets an image. The second has 6 cells, the sixth being empty.

`showframe` is used here to show the way the width and height of the page are filled by the grid cells.

[image: image grids]

Note that the vertical and horizontal spacing are due to the images not being very well-chosen given the proportions of the grid cells available. In order to make them fit, they get scaled but, to avoid distorting them, their aspect ratios are maintained, creating vertical or horizontal padding within the affected cells.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_student_grid_seq
\int_new:N \l_student_cols_int
\int_new:N \l_student_rows_int
\int_new:N \g_student_count_int
\coffin_new:N \l_student_image_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_student_images_coffin
\tl_new:N \l_student_graphics_tl
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \student_gridset:n #1
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_student_grid_seq { x } { #1 }
  \seq_get_left:NN \l_student_grid_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \int_set:Nn \l_student_cols_int { \l_tmpa_tl }
  \seq_get_right:NN \l_student_grid_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \int_set:Nn \l_student_rows_int { \l_tmpa_tl }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \student_graphics:nn #1 #2
{
  \includegraphics [ #1 ] { #2 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \student_graphics:nn { Vn }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \student_boximage:nnn #1 #2 #3
{
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \includegraphics { #3 } }
  \dim_compare:nT { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box + \box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box > #2 }
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_student_graphics_tl { height = #2 , }
  }
  \dim_compare:nT { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box > #1 }
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_student_graphics_tl { width = #1 , }
  }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_student_graphics_tl { keepaspectratio = true }
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_student_image_coffin { #1 }
  {
    \vbox_to_ht:nn { #2 }
    {
      \skip_vertical:N \fill
      \student_graphics:Vn \l_student_graphics_tl { #3 }
      \skip_vertical:N \fill
    }
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \student_boximage:nnn { VVn }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \student_processimages:nnnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 #5
{
  \int_gzero:N \g_student_count_int
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { #1 / #3 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpb_dim { #2 / #4 }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #5 }
  {
    \student_boximage:VVn \l_tmpa_dim \l_tmpb_dim { ##1 }
    \int_compare:nTF { \g_student_count_int = 0 }
    {
      \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_student_images_coffin { l } { b } \l_student_image_coffin { l } { t } { 0pt } { 0pt }
    }
    {
      \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_student_images_coffin { \l_student_image_coffin-r } { \l_student_image_coffin-t } \l_student_image_coffin { l } { t } { 0pt } { 0pt }
    }
    \int_gincr:N \g_student_count_int
    \int_compare:nT { \g_student_count_int = \l_student_cols_int }
    { \int_gzero:N \g_student_count_int  }
  }
  \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_student_images_coffin { B } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \student_processimages:nnnnn { VVVVV }
\keys_define:nn { student / images }
{
  grid .code:n = {
    \student_gridset:n { #1 }
  },
  grid .initial:n = { 2 x 2 },
  images .clist_set:N = \l_student_images_clist,
  total~width .dim_set:N = \l_student_width_dim,
  total~height .dim_set:N = \l_student_height_dim,
}
\NewDocumentCommand \images { m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \dim_set_eq:NN \parindent \c_zero_dim
    \keys_set:nn { student / images } { total~width = \linewidth , total~height = \textheight }
    \keys_set:nn { student / images } { #1 }
    \student_processimages:VVVVV \l_student_width_dim \l_student_height_dim \l_student_cols_int \l_student_rows_int \l_student_images_clist
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\images{%
  images={cath-gadael-chartref,cathod,cath,coeden-nadolig-2014},
}

\images{%
  images={tspcd,cauldron,duck,tiger,example-image-c},
  grid=3x2,
}

\end{document}
```

## EDIT

If you really need an `images` environment and to use `im` as the name of the key, then you can adapt the definition of the keys and change the definition of `\images` into an `images` environment.

For example, we can rename the key `images` as `im`:

```
\keys_define:nn { student / images }
{
  grid .code:n = {
    \student_gridset:n { #1 }
  },
  grid .initial:n = { 2 x 2 },
  im .clist_set:N = \l_student_images_clist,
  total~width .dim_set:N = \l_student_width_dim,
  total~height .dim_set:N = \l_student_height_dim,
}
```

and change `\images` into an `images` environment similar to the one in the question:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment { images } { m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \begin{center}
      \dim_set_eq:NN \parindent \c_zero_dim
      \keys_set:nn { student / images } { total~width = \linewidth , total~height = \textheight }
      \keys_set:nn { student / images } { #1 }
      \student_processimages:VVVVV \l_student_width_dim \l_student_height_dim \l_student_cols_int \l_student_rows_int \l_student_images_clist
      \skip_vertical:N \medskipamount
}{
    \end{center}
  \group_end:
}
```

As in the original pseudocode, this uses a `center` environment around the images and the environment's contents. (I assume the contents of the environment should be wrapped, too, else there is no reason to use an environment at all.)

Then, rather than `\images{images={<list>}}`, we can say, `\begin{images}{im={<list>}} ... \end{images}`:

```
\begin{images}
  {%
    im={cath-gadael-chartref,cathod,cath,coeden-nadolig-2014},
  }
\end{images}

\begin{images}
  {%
    im={tspcd,cauldron,duck,tiger,example-image-c},
    grid=3x2,
    total height=.5\textheight,
    total width=.9\textwidth,
  }
  This is some content for the \verb|images| environment.
\end{images}
```

The main difference here is that the environment takes a mandatory argument rather than an optional one. This seems to reflect the intended usage: we don't want the argument to be optional given that the environment makes no sense without a list of images.

If you really wanted the argument to be optional, you could say, for example,

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment { images } { O { im = {example-image-a} } }
```

and then write

```
\begin{images}
  [im={<image-1>,<image-2>,<image-3>,...}]
  ....
```

but this seems non-ideal since the user really should get a warning rather than `example-image-a` in case no images are specified. Moreover, this will cause weird errors in certain cases e.g. if the user supplies an argument but does not provide a value for `im`. You can avoid this by specifying a default list elsewhere or by testing to see the key has a value. But that introduces a great many complexities in the service of a less transparent user interface, so seems to be a lose-lose situation all round.

Comment: Thanks. Since for my application the environment,  that in my pseudocode is called `images` already exists and because I don't know latex3 very well, I tried to combine your code with Christian Hupfer's example and replaced `\loopovercommandkey[width=2cm]{\commandkey{im}}` by `\images{images=\commandkey{im}}`. However this doesn't work and complains that the file `ente1,ente2,ente3` is not found (because it doesn't seem to split the list). Do you have an idea of how to make that work?

Comment: @student Please see edit. I've never used `keycommand`, but it is easy to adapt the code to create an environment and use the `im` key name, if that's desired.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The argument should indeed be optional. The environment in my real case doesn't only insert images (and has many more keys ), it does other things as well and optionally you can insert images (images in one minipage and side by side in the other minipage the other stuff). But you are right, if it was the only purpose to insert images (as it seems from my minimal example), the argument should be mandatory, but that's not the case.

Comment: That makes more sense and is really why I included the relevant modification in the answer. In that case, you probably need to test if the list is empty etc.

Comment: after Christian Hupfer critique that I changed the question with the bonus part (see commend below his answer), I created a new question. If you want, please move your answer to it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312436/pass-a-list-to-a-keycommand-or-keyenvironment-and-arrange-them-in-a-grid

Comment: @student I don't really think this answer addresses your new question, which is more specific than the question I answered and the specifics are ones this answer doesn't take any account of, even with the edit.